# Apache2 MPM_Event Conf to avoid Scoreboard full error

Tags: apache-2.4, mpm-worker

I have a couple servers running apache2 service to hose REST APIs and traffic is descent. For now, apache2 is set to start 2 servers so I see two 222-data processes. Rarely, but from time to time, servers fails because of "scoreboard is full" error which is known [Apache2 bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53555). When that happens I notice my processes are 4 not 2 and two of the processes are using 100%+ cpu, so I usually manually kill them and restart Apache2 which is not idea or reliable in long term.

I have read here and there aboutn setting up of MPM-Event.config to minimize errors like that and I even tried to update Apache2 on Ubuntu16 to 2.4.39. I looked up defauly MPM configs as below but not sure what is best change to minimze MPM errors. The post [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/516373/what-is-the-meaning-of-ah00485-scoreboard-is-full-not-at-maxrequestworkers) has some suggestions but I am not as experienced with networking and specifically Apache2 and want to make sure I dont break production servers by applying changes suggested.

I am sure, the tuning changes are handled differently from one case to another, but I would appreciate any tips.

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
        StartServers                     2
        MinSpareThreads          25
        MaxSpareThreads          75
        ThreadLimit                      64
        ThreadsPerChild          25
        MaxRequestWorkers         150
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What was on the scoreboard when the problem occurred?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that, but I am thinking it usually happens when there is a drop in user authentication service I use which is a served as API to my server code.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html